# How to get object's byte range using AWS S3 SDK for .Net

Tags: amazon-s3, get

I cannot see anything in the AWS S3 SDK for .Net that would allow me to get a range of bytes from S3 object. Is making a GET HTTP request with Range header to the S3 REST API the only way? In this case, is there anything in the SDK to generate the Authorization header for the request? Building the header manually looks quite complicated and time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `Amazon.S3.Model.GetObjectRequest` class has a `ByteRange` property. Don't know how I missed it!